# Video component of react-native-video is requesting twice for the same uri

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm using the `Video` component of `react-native-video`.
I'm getting an external video using `http` (not `https`).

The video is obtained and played correctly. But I noticed that the component makes two request for the same video. Why is that?

PS: I've used `useEffect` to corroborate if the parent component is mounted twice, but it's not.

Versions:
`react-native-video`: 5.0.2
`react-native`: 0.61.4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not familiar with this, but for example a classic browser would make an Options request first and then the actual request. Is it possible this might be the case ? In general every request you are trying to make, a browser would make an OPTIONS request first to check things like CORS and some other things.

Comment: Hello, both are GET request. I've compared the two request made for the same video and the only difference is the REMOTE_PORT in the request.